# Java : CompletableFuture<?> Capturing

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a variable `CompletableFuture<?> completableFuture`. I want to be able to complete it with object of any type. For example : `completableFuture.complete(new String("Hello"))` or something else. This is a design requirement for my project. But I am getting the following error : `complete
(capture<? extends java.lang.Object>)
in CompletableFuture cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String[])`

I know the issue is something related to capturing wildcards in Java but I cannot find a well-explained solution to this problem on the internet that helps me out.

Can you please tell me a way to complete my CompletableFuture with any object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CompletableFuture<Object>`, which will accept any type:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> completableFuture = ...;
completableFuture.complete(new Object());
completableFuture.complete("abc");
completableFuture.complete(new String[] { "abc" });
completableFuture.complete(null);
completableFuture.complete(new ArrayList<String>());
```

The problem is that `CompletableFuture<?>` is compatible with many concrete generic types, suh as `CompletableFuture<String>`, `CompletableFuture<String[]>`. And that's why the compiler prohibits calls like `completableFuture.complete(String[])` (potential for calling `complete` with incompatible types).

The alternative would be to declare your completable future as `CompletableFuture<? super Object>`, but doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: In my project I need to maintain an array of completableFutures where I can randomly set and retrieve completable futures. Hence I switched from Object to '?'. I will give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: @KeyurJain Maybe you'll have better luck (or design better) with a collection, such as `List<CompletableFuture<Object>>`...